# python / pandas - MultiIndexing - eliminate the use of global variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, global-variables

I am using pandas to import a dataframe from excel in order to sort, make changes and run some simple addition and division on the data.

My code is working but it has global variables throughout. I think this is poor practice and I want to somehow eliminate these global variables but I am confused on how I can go about doing this.

I'm not sure how I can further modify my dataframe with indexing and slicing without declaring global variables.

```
mydf = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

new_indexes = df.set_index(['apple', 'cherry', 'banana'])

new_indexes['apples and cherries'] = new_indexes['apple'] + new_indexes['cherries']

sliced = multi.loc(axis = 0)[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'fruits']]

total_fruits = sliced.loc[:, 'grapes', 'watermelon', 'orange'].sum(axis=1)
```

That's a snippet of my code. As you can see I am referring to the global variables in order to further modify my dataframe. I need to eliminate the global variables. I am trying to create functions to help clean up my code.

My main question is how can I refer to my data and changes without assigning global variables to my code?

If I wanted to go about defining a class and reassigning the variables to properties would I be able to do something like this?

```
class MyDf:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_df(self):
        return pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    
    def set_index(self):
        self._multi_index = df.set_index(['apple', 'cherry', 'banana']) 

    def add_totals(self)
        self.set_indexes['apples and cherries'] = set_indexes['apple']+ new_indexes['cherries']
```

Thank you

Comment: In your second snippet, `get_df(self)` does _return_ a dataframe instead of making it a class attribute. To change this, replace `return pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')` by `self.df = pd.read_excel(data.xlsx')`. Also your methods currently do not refer to `df` as a class attribute (`self.df`). Finally, note that your class attributes are currently hard-coded. While this might not be a problem if the use of this class is a one-time thing, changing the methods accordingly to allow individual assignment of attributes for each class object may be the better alternative.

Comment: if I wanted to fix my class attributes so that they are no longer hardcoded would I declare them in the __ini__(self) ? thank you for your help so far!

Comment: This could be done both in `__init__()` or in the regular methods of the class. I think in your case it may make sense to do `__init__(self, filename): self.df = pd.read_excel(str(filename))` so that each class object is initialised with a df already. You could then change the other methods so that they take the specifics of the operation as arguments (e.g. the index labels in `set_index`). This way, you would not have to provide all the arguments when initialising the class object at once.

Comment: thank you that does make sense. Should I be including any other attributes in my __init_?

Comment: This really depends on the case at hand, but at least with your example I think it's reasonable to leave it at the df, since it is central to all methods.

Comment: okay thank you. When you say that they are hardcoded, that is because I have the attributes declared inside my methods rather than in the __init__? Thank you so much for your help. You clarified things for me!

Comment: With hard-coding I mean that the specs of your variables are fixed in the class definition itself. Generally, it is good practice to avoid hard-coding. You can find more information, for example, here: [link](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/SimplePythonData/HardCoding.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you could do, dependent on the overall structure of your code and your goal. Without knowing more about your case and, for example, seeing how the snippet you provided is embedded into the rest of your code, those are only possible solutions.

You could define a **function**, make it take a dataframe as an argument, perform operations on it and then return the modified dataframe. The function could also simply take a filename as argument, so that the respective df is created within the function to begin with. If you do not need to refer to intermediary variables such as `new_indexes` or `sliced` later in the code, using a function to perform the operations *might* be a good way to go.

You could also define a **Class**, make the variables into properties of objects of that class and write methods to perform the respective operations you want to do. This would have the advantage that you could still access your variables, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I go about the defining a class option? I am confused how I could change those variables into properties of that class. I will update my code in the original post.